# How to set Username in http post in java?

Tags: java, android, http

the http://username:password@whatever.com 
syntax does not seem to work with org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient
I'm doing a POST

ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache HTTP client has built-in [support for authentication](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/authentication.html). Use that instead of trying to embed it in the URL. There is [sample code for doing Basic auth](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientPreemptiveBasicAuthentication.java) on its [examples page](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/examples.html)

Answer (score 2):

The http://username:password@whatever.com syntax is syntactic sugar that browsers implement to let the user provide credentials for HTTP BASIC. It is **not** part of the URL syntax.

Under the hood, this is translated to to a request to http://whatever.com with a special header called `Authorization` which contains the username and password coded with Base64. This is how the HTTP specification specifies it. It doesn't matter whether it is a GET or a POST request.

In order to use the apache client you must do exactly that. You can encode the header using the [Base64](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html) class of Apache Commons, and the format is expected to be `username + ":" + password` as the value, so something along the lines of:

```
Base64.encodeBase64String(String.format(%s:%s,username,password).getBytes());
```

See also [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) for a more thorough explanation of the headers.